# Where can I get a comprehensive criminal dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, predictive-modeling, dataset, data

I want to create a machine learning model to predict the probability of Person committing crime in future. Given his/her past crime history, age, gender, race, employment history, family information (Married, Having young kids, etc.), financial status etc.

Please suggest some data sources having such information to train the model.

Comment: There's no global crime datasets, I've found some from countries like [France](https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/chiffres-departementaux-mensuels-relatifs-aux-crimes-et-delits-enregistres-par-les-services-de-police-et-de-gendarmerie-depuis-janvier-1996/), or cities like [Salt Lake City](https://github.com/kylesykes/stl-crime-data).

Keep in mind that even with a perfect data set you'll be correlating age/race/etc. with rate of crime *convictions*, which can be the result of social/institutional bias that makes it likely different than the number of crimes *commited*.

Comment: What you want isn't *crime data*, but *convictions*. I doubt this is available, even if the personal data is anonymised. I know people working on this sort of problem - they work very closely with the responsible government department and have very strong restrictions on data access.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Bureau of Justice Statistics](https://www.bjs.gov/rawdata.cfm) site. Other sites that you might find interesting would be [U.S. City Census Crimes Data](http://us-city.census.okfn.org/dataset/crime-stats). Of course, [Knoema](https://knoema.com/atlas/topics/crime/datasets), will provide more of an international flare that you might find useful.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at :

https://data.cityofchicago.org/Public-Safety/Crimes-2001-to-present/ijzp-q8t2

It has the data of crimes from 2001 to present. This data is extracted from the Chicago Police Department's CLEAR (Citizen Law Enforcement Analysis and Reporting) system

Answer (score 0):

There was a Kaggle competition last year about [San Francisco Crime Classification](https://www.kaggle.com/c/sf-crime).
You can [download](https://www.kaggle.com/c/sf-crime/data) the training set and the test set which contains criminal records from 2003 to 2015 in SF. It just need a registration on the website.
You also can access to different interesting [kernels](https://www.kaggle.com/c/sf-crime/kernels) about this subject.